# Why doesn't LibreOffice handle .doc[x] files well [and will this be ever fixed]?

Tags: libreoffice, docx

I've been using OpenOffice for years now then I switched to [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org) as soon as [The Document Foundation](http://www.documentfoundation.org/) released install binaries months ago. I must admit that I'm very satisfied because I can do whatever I want with LibreOffice when it comes to writing documents, creating slides, etc.

However when opening a .doc[x] file or saving to .doc things do not go well..

Anyone knows why LibreOffice support for .doc[x] is not that good? And do we have a chance to see a fix for that in the future? Is Microsoft trying to make .doc[x] hard for developers?

Comment: http://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Office Format documentation is actually a bit vague. The docs are huge, [hundreds of pages long](http://developers.slashdot.org/story/08/06/30/1942211/Microsoft-Releases-Pre-2007-Binary-File-Format-Specs), and hard to get right. There literally are sections that say 'do what Word 95 does', which makes it hard to get right. I'm sure you opened a doc from Word 95 and it looked different in Word 2003. If Microsoft can't even be consistent, it's hard for outsiders to be better.

Comment: You would think **more pages** of documents would make a standard more precise.

Answer (score -1):

The Office File Formats have always been well documented.  Even the old 2003 formats.  It is just a lot of reading and I believe people just don't take the time to read documentation these days.  On top of that, **writing good software isn't easy**.  I'd give those guys a break man.  They are working for **free**.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205(v=office.12).aspx#office2007WordFileFormat

In general, MSDN has been a high standard for documentation.  You won't find that elsewhere.